# Possible to identify inheritor in request body without specifying type?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, jackson

I have a case where my request body has an object which is backed by inheritance.
So when I use @requestbody and do not explicitly specify the type of subclass it does not pick/determine that automatically.
Is there a way to do it without this :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Fence.class, name = "fence"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Rectangle.class, name = "rectangle"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Point.class, name = "point"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "circle")
})
public class Element implements Serializable {
}
```

Is there any open-source library which handles this, when a requestBody comes in it automatically detects the instance of the sub class.

I would have used JsonTypeInfo.Id#DEDUCTION but it fails to work when we have a nested object in the subclass.

```
public class Rectangle extends Element implements Serializable {

    private Point leftDown;
    private Point rightUpper;

}

public class Point extends Element implements Serializable {

    private double lng;
    private double lat;
}
```

Gives me this error

```
"JSON parse error: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.mapabc.entity.Point]: Cannot deduce unique subtype of `com.mapabc.entity.Point` (2 candidates match); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.mapabc.entity.Point]: Cannot deduce unique subtype of `com.mapabc.entity.Point` (2 candidates match)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 8, column: 9] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.moveinsync.geofencing.models.Geofence[\"geometry\"]->com.mapabc.entity.Rectangle[\"leftDown\"])"
```

Here is the element class ->

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Fence.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Rectangle.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Point.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Circle.class)
})
public class Element implements Serializable {
    public CommandArgs<String, String> getCommandArgs(String key, String member){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Point class ->

```
public class Point extends Element implements Serializable {

private double lng;
private double lat;

public Point() {}

public Point(double lng, double lat) {
    this.lng = lng;
    this.lat = lat;
}

public double getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(double lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Point{" +
            "lng=" + lng +
            ", lat=" + lat +
            '}';
}
```

}

Rectangle class ->

```
public class Rectangle extends Element implements Serializable {

    private Point leftDown;
    private Point rightUpper;

    @Override
    public CommandArgs<String, String> getCommandArgs(String key, String member) {
        double lng1 = leftDown.getLng();
        double lat1 = leftDown.getLat();
        double lng2 = rightUpper.getLng();
        double lat2 = rightUpper.getLat();
        return new CommandArgs<>(StringCodec.UTF8).add(key).add(member).add("BOUNDS").add(lng1).add(lat1).add(lng2).add(lat2);
    }

    public Rectangle() {}

    public Rectangle(Point leftDown, Point rightUpper) {
        this.leftDown = leftDown;
        this.rightUpper = rightUpper;
    }

    public Point getLeftDown() {
        return leftDown;
    }

    public void setLeftDown(Point leftDown) {
        this.leftDown = leftDown;
    }

    public Point getRightUpper() {
        return rightUpper;
    }

    public void setRightUpper(Point rightUpper) {
        this.rightUpper = rightUpper;
    }


}
```

This is the request body ->

```
{
        "leftDown": {
            "lng" : 4.0,
            "lat" : 1.0
        },
        "rightUpper" : {
            "lng" : 1.0,
            "lat" : 4.0
        }
    }
```

With just 2 classes everything works fine but if we add a third class it breaks ->

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Rectangle.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Point.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(Circle.class)
})
public class Element implements Serializable {

}

public class Circle extends Element implements Serializable {
    private double lng;
    private double lat;
    private int r;
}
```

Comment: You can use the [JsonTypeInfo.Id#DEDUCTION](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#DEDUCTION).

Comment: I have explained in the question by editing it right now that why this will not work for me @dariosicily

Comment: Your message error says "Cannot deduce unique subtype of com.mapabc.entity.Point (2 candidates match)", so for jackson library `Point` is an abstract class or similar with subclasses.

Comment: Yes, thats the tricky part, on how to get this working.

Comment: You have to use  `JsonTypeInfo.DEDUCTION` for `Point` class too.

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't work. Added JsonTypeInfo.DEDUCTION on Point class as well

Comment: Please include in your question a runnable example of a json input file and how it should be deserialized with all classes code involved.

Comment: I have added it. (@RequestBody Element element) Fetching it like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253450/discussion-between-mukund-mundhra-and-dariosicily).

Comment: So the issue is when we add more than 2 subclasses. You can check it. It will break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in the definition of the `Point` and `Circle` classes as subclasses of the `Element` class:

```
public class Point extends Element implements Serializable {

    private double lng;
    private double lat;
}

public class Circle extends Element implements Serializable {
    private double lng;
    private double lat;
    private int r;
}
```

Basically when the jackson library reads the `"leftDown": {"lng" : 4.0, "lat" : 1.0}` property from the json file, it can interpret it as a representation either of a `Point` object or a `Circle` object without the definition of its radius at the same time, there the exception due to the ambiguous representation. One of the possible solution and maybe the most natural idea is redefine the `Circle` class as a couple of a `Point` center and its radius (up to you another possible solution you can consider more adapt to your needs):

```
public class Circle extends Element implements Serializable {

    Point center;
    private int r;
}
```